# Using Perl to perform POST request to a REST API using Basic auth

Tags: rest, perl, post

I'm fairly new to Perl. (using Perl 5)
There's a requirement to call a REST API endpoint which expects a POST request and it only supports Basic auth.

I tried below logic but I'm getting: *Can't call method "clone" on unblessed reference at C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/HTTP/Message.pm*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode qw(encode_utf8);
use HTTP::Request ();
use JSON::MaybeXS qw(encode_json);
#use REST::Client;
use MIME::Base64;

my $username = '';
my $password = '';

my $url = 'https://testapi.com/webapi/AddData';
#my $header = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'];
my $header = {Accept => 'application/json', Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)};
my $data = {GroupName=> 'City', Member=> 'New York'};
my $encoded_data = encode_utf8(encode_json($data));
my $r = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $url, $header, $encoded_data);
print $r->responseContent();
```

I may be completely wrong here with this logic but how can we correct or construct a proper Basic auth POST REST API call using PERL.

The API in question accepts data in following format:

```
{
        "GroupName": "City",
        "Member": "New York"
}
```

and if the call is succeded it returns the following data of which we need the "ReturnValue" data:

```
{
    "IsPass": true,
    "ReturnValue": "New city has been added"
}
```

**EDIT**

Got this working by tweaking the header logic:

```
my $header = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)];
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't actually sent the request. You just constructed it. As the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request#Simple-POST) says:

```perl
my $r = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $url, $header, $encoded_data);
# at this point, we could send it via LWP::UserAgent
# my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
# my $res = $ua->request($r);
```

Also, `responseContent` doesn't exist in [HTTP::Request](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Request) nor [HTTP::Response](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Response) (or HTTP::Whatever). It exists in [REST::Client](http://p3rl.org/REST::Client), though, which you commented out.

Comment: I'm not getting how I can install this REST::Client module in order to be able to use it

Comment: You can ask a new question. But I guess "How do I install a Perl module?" has already been answered many times.

Comment: Used this cpan REST::Client and it works.
Initially I was using ppm command

Comment: What would be the best way to print the API response specifically for the IsPass value?

Comment: I've tried the following which works but how can I further only access and print "IsPass" attribute:
my $content  = $res->decoded_content();
print $content;

Comment: Create a new question to ask a new question. You can reference the older one for context.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, look at my coments mark as [Welcho]

```
use warnings;
use Encode qw(encode_utf8);
use HTTP::Request ();
use JSON::MaybeXS qw(encode_json);
#use REST::Client;
use MIME::Base64;
use LWP::UserAgent; # [Welcho] Add this

my $username = '';
my $password = '';

my $url = 'https://testapi.com/webapi/AddData';
#my $header = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'];
my $header = {Accept => 'application/json', Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)};
my $data = {GroupName=> 'City', Member=> 'New York'};
my $encoded_data = encode_utf8(encode_json($data));
my $r = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $url, $header, $encoded_data);

# [Welcho] comment this print $r->responseContent();

#[Welcho]
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua->request($r);
print $res->decoded_content;
```

Comment: How this can be done if its mutual authentication and not the basic auth? Thanks in advance.